# Amazon AWS VPC Performance Advantages

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

We have a simple setup that consists of...

```
1 EC Instance for HTTP/PHP requests
1 RDS Instance for our Database requests
```

Currently our two servers do not use VPC to communicate.

I was wondering if there would be performance advantages to setting the two servers up on a VPC. Would a VPC lower the response time when the servers communicate?

Answer (score 4):

No, VPC would not be any faster because it is almost definitely implemented as an overlay network (i.e. tunnelled packets which are transported on the same network as non-VPC connectivity is). In fact, VPC would be slightly slower because of the additional cost of encapsulation, decapsulation, and routing.

Comment: Then is there ever a point to putting both inside a VPC?